# gsheets inserting python dictonary using batchupdate

Tags: python, google-apis-explorer, pygsheets

I am new to gheets and am looking for a way to insert the data that I have scraped into gheets that is currently in a python dictionary. I would like to do this in a batch process so my spider can update multiple fields at once.

```
{'page_url': 'https://www.websiteurl.com', 'company': 'my company', 'location': 'The Netherlands',
                  'price_excl_vat': '30000'}
```

I tried to build a json request but am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'. I know its because the data field takes a string but thought qould be able to take a dictionary and cant seem to find how to do thie. Been at this all day and just cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body =  {

    {
     "requests": [
      {
       "insertRange": {
        "range": {
         "sheetId": '12345tutu',

        },
       }
      },
      {
       "pasteData": {
        "data":  {'page_url': 'https://www.websiteurl.com', 'company': 'my company', 'location': 'The Netherlands',
                  'price_excl_vat': '30000'},

       }
      }
     ]
    }

}

request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
response = request.execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove a pair of `{}`:

```
batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
     "requests": [
      {
       "insertRange": {
        "range": {
         "sheetId": '12345tutu',

        },
       }
      },
      {
       "pasteData": {
        "data":  {'page_url': 'https://www.websiteurl.com', 'company': 'my company', 'location': 'The Netherlands',
                  'price_excl_vat': '30000'},

       }
      }
     ]
    }
```

It creates a set containing a dictionnary, and that is not possible, because as the error says, sets elements have to be hashable, and a dict is not.

Comment: From where? I have tried removing it from the data but the : gives an error. The thing is I need to map this to the correct column.

Comment: You have to remove the external braces. It works on my computer, check the code of my answer.

Comment: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1e-_efoHgfn0cnA0HAS-V4HrVw0qIsrptLXESrUIYjE0:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'requests[0].insert_range.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), "1e-_efoHgfn0cnA0HAS-V4HrVw0qIsrptLXESrUIYjE0"
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "page_url" at 'requests[1].paste_data.data': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "company" at 'requests[1].paste_data.data': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "location" at 'requests[1].paste_data.data': Cannot find field.

Comment: Ive check the sheetID and spreadsheet id and these are also the fields that are in the spreadsheet. I dont get why I am now getting a 400 error

Comment: OK, so your first problem is solved. You are talking about another issue, which is not a python but a ggsheet API issue.